# LibGDX - How to save generated FreeType fonts

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I have problem with fonts lin LibGDX. I have three different fonts and parameters:

```
parameter_score = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
//Some parameters..
font_score = generator.generateFont(parameter_score);

parameter_Big = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
//Some parameters..
font_Big = generator.generateFont(parameter_Big);

parameter_Small = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
//Some parameters..
font_Small = generator.generateFont(parameter_Small);
```

and it is very slow to generate fonts. When the app starts, i see black screen for about 3 seconds. I heard about method, when I generate fonts only first time, then I save it to some file, and when I lunch app next time, it will get generated fonts from file. But i dont know how to save, and load generated fonts. Do anyone know?

Comment: Freetypefont is nice to keep storage low. Since you are saving why don't you just generate a `BitmapFont` with `Hiero`?

Comment: I have never heard about Hiero before, what is it?

Comment: it generates a `BitmapFont` for you on your desired size. The same as what `FreeTypeFontGenerator` does but then before you compile, you put the `BitmapFont` files into your assets folder and can use them. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

Answer (score 1):

**BitmapFontWriter**

BitmapFontWriter is a class in gdx-tools which can write BMFont files from a BitmapFontData instance. This allows a font to be generated using FreeTypeFontGenerator, then written to a font file and PNG files. BitmapFontWriter has the benefit that it can be more easily run from scripts and can make use of FreeTypeFontGenerator's shadows and borders. Otherwise, the output is very similar to Hiero, though Hiero avoids writing a glyph image multiple times if different character codes render the same glyph.

Usage can look like this:

```
new LwjglApplication(new ApplicationAdapter() {
    public void create () {
        FontInfo info = new FontInfo();
        info.padding = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        FreeTypeFontParameter param = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
        param.size = 13;
        param.gamma = 2f;
        param.shadowOffsetY = 1;
        param.renderCount = 3;
        param.shadowColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.45f);
        param.characters = Hiero.EXTENDED_CHARS;
        param.packer = new PixmapPacker(512, 512, Format.RGBA8888, 2, false, new SkylineStrategy());

        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.absolute("some-font.ttf"));
        FreeTypeBitmapFontData data = generator.generateData(param);

        BitmapFontWriter.writeFont(data, new String[] {"font.png"},
            Gdx.files.absolute("font.fnt"), info, 512, 512);
        BitmapFontWriter.writePixmaps(param.packer.getPages(), Gdx.files.absolute("imageDir"), name);

        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero#bitmapfontwriter

Comment: How to generate and save as file is clear.. How to load and use it

Comment: @iappmaker 
AssetManager().setLoader(BitmapFont::class.java, bitmapFontLoader)

assetManager.load(filePath, BitmapFont::class.java, BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter())
assetManager.finishLoading()
assetManager.get(filePath, BitmapFont::class.java)